# can we resolve any deferred with any response in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I cant understand, certain things in this code http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application
This code, this trying to resend same request(the one user requests before logging in) after the user logs in.

My question

1. Inside the retry function, they are resloving a deffered with the
   response of a request that is sent after the user logs in. The
   response and the deffered are no way related to each other. Why they
   should do this?

-

```
function retry(req) {
    $http(req.config).then(function(response) {
        req.deferred.resolve(response);
    });
}
```

Please have a look at the code in the above url for understanding how the `retry` method works.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve a promise with whatever you want.  In this case, a promise was returned to the application when the 401 status code/error was first encountered.  Now, after the `loginConfirmed` event, the request is sent again and the response is used to resolve that promise.